# Is there an equivalent of FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm in the process of updating our application from old asp.net forms authentication to use the asp.net identity framework.

We currently have PDF generation code (evopdf) that takes place on a separate thread (but still within the web server process). When the PDF generation occurs, we need to assign the authentication cookie. Currently we do this using this method:

```
var authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, false);
pdfConverter.HttpRequestCookies.Add(authCookie.Name, authCookie.Value);
```

Is there an equivalent way in ASP.NET Identity to create the cookie without having to actually assign a cookie to a HTTP response via `IAuthenticationManager.SignIn()` ?